# Question answered in duplicate has no accepted answer

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

So, I am hoping this is the right place to bring this up.

I just got some activity on an old question I answered, and found that this old question: [Python re.search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20240239/1561176) which has no accepted answer has been duplicated here [Python re.search() and re.findall()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244228/python-re-search-and-re-findall) and does have an accepted answer.

Both questions were asked by the same user, about the same topic, and I answered both questions.

I think it would be a good idea to close the first one (without an accepted answer) and direct users to the newer question which duplicates it (with much more pertinent information, and an accepted answer)

When I try to mark the old one as a duplicate (which is what I believe the correct solution should be) I can not, because the new one is already marked as a duplicate of the old one.

Can this be sorted out somehow? What is the correct way to resolve this questions status? (It bothers me to see questions without accepted answers)

Comment: So...you want to *reverse* the direction of the duplicate?

Comment: @CodyGray I suppose that is a much simpler way to put it.

Comment: That question has *much* stronger google SEO for some reason, 40 times more views than the closed one.  I'd guess it is because of the very non-descriptive title, anybody that queries "python re.search" might assume the Q+A could have something useful.  And it is on the first page of hits.  Are you sure you want to close a question that is *that* much more popular?  Best not to tinker with that kind of magic :)

Comment: The amount of views is irrelevant if answers can't be found. Even though the specific question in question is not a very well defined one, and even if the answer does do something. I think the site strives for a higher standard. And here we have a question asked twice with an actual answer, lets link the first question to its answer. There is no way to know that the question has been answered in another question without some sleuthing, and that's not fair to the simple end user.

Comment: @InbarRose why not update the old answer since it is yours with the more useful info if it's really a total duplicate.

Comment: Agree. Edit and improve the active one.

Comment: My concern is that the old answer will never be accepted, since the asking user is inactive as far as I can tell. My assumption is that even with the higher result on google, people will not stay long when no accepted answer is present.

Comment: Anyway, I did as suggested, http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20240276/3